# Is there an AOP solution for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, aop

I see that there is PostSharp AOP support for Silverlight, but is there a product that works like the Castle DynamicProxy library, but in Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For runtime AOP you can use Castle DynamicProxy. Yep, it works.
I just grabbed the binaries for Castle Silverlight DynamicProxy for the Silverlight RhinoMocks package @ http://www.ayende.com/20/section.aspx/download/230

For compile time AOP, consider Mono.Cecil which I've used successfully on Silverlight assemblies. Presumably, other frameworks that enable compile time AOP should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Castle Dynamic Proxy itself? or LinFu?

Comment: Are you asking a question with another question? :-)

Dynamic proxy seems to have a broken silverlight version, and I can't seem to determine if LinFu supports Silverlight.

Comment: I have seen Castle Dynamic Proxy working with Silverlight. There is no official Silverlight port of LinFu.DynamicProxy, but you should be able to create one (and make it available only for everyone :) ) in a short amount of time

Comment: LinFu.DynamicProxy supports SilverLight, and the DLL itself is only 20KB: http://is.gd/aQGB2

Comment: @plaureano: Thanks I didn't know there was a silverlight port already.